# Do i need Jedis to use Redis cache in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, jedis

I am new to Redis and want to implement Redis Cache in my Spring Boot application. I have gone through few blogs and saw some using Jedis the java client for Redis while few using just spring-boot-starter-data-redis

Should I use Jedis when working with Production ready applications. What problems it solves over just spring-boot-starter-data-redis?

I tried with spring-boot-starter-data-redis and caching is working with Spring annotations like @Cacheable, @CacheEvict but I need to understand should I be using Jedis and then create Redis Template and Redis Connection Factory and all these stuff for caching

Comment: welcome and please check [avoid asking question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have a better understanding of Spring Cache and Redis, it's important to grasp the core components separately, this is a short overview of Jedis, spring-data-redis, and Spring Redis Cache

- **Jedis**: it's a low-level implementation, it acctually works as an Redis driver you can read about it more on https://github.com/redis/jedis
- **spring-data-redis**: it's a spring-boot starter which gives to you a high-level API to interact with Redis data store, (actually some already written Templates ready to use), but under the hood, spring-data-redis relies on *Jedis*(or other low-level driver implementation) to interact with the Redis store (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/tree/main)
- **[Spring Redis Cache](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/6.1/integration/cache.html)**: spring-redis-data implements the cache specifications, so it means the Redis Spring Cache uses the spring-redis-data as an implementation

In summary, when working with Spring Cache and Redis you should provide a Redis driver implementation  (Jedis, Lettuce)  to *spring-redis-data*, but you can use either high-level API (for cache are @Cacheable, @CacheEvict, and for spring-redis-data *RedisTemplate*) or a low-level like Jedis, depends on the use cases you have

Comment: thank you so much for the response, this helps a lot